# From where is this sequence in the Apollo 13 (movie) extra material showing Gene Kranz?

Tags: nasa, history, apollo-13

In the Apollo 13 movie extra material, there are several documentary shots interspersed with commentary about the makings of the movie.

I am interested in the sequence beginning at about 29 minutes (DVD title 1, chapter 7, approximately 2 min 20 sec into the chapter) with Gene Kranz where he talks about the initial problems being referred to as a "funny" and there is a cut to a significantly lower-quality shot showing (him?) in likely Mission Control during the actual mission. There's also a minute later a sequence showing Sy Liebergot discussing the problem of loss of electrical power and oxygen.

I know I have seen these sequences before, and I am certain that I've seen a bit more of both of them; alternatively, something where Kranz and Liebergot said something *extremely* similar almost down to the specific wording.

**Where are those sequences from?** Is that NASA footage, some third-party documentary footage that was reused for the extra material, or Howard original footage? **Where can I find it** (like e.g. documentary title, original broadcast network, archive number with NASA, ...)?

As a bonus question (not required for a valid answer to this question), in what other documentaries has the material been used?

The relevant portions of the ending credits appear to be (which doesn't really help me very much):

```
ARCHIVAL FOOTAGE

NASA

Courtesy of the
NATIONAL BROADCASTING COMPANY, INC.

CARSON PRODUCTIONS


ADDITIONAL FOOTAGE

THE BERKELEY GROUP

GRB ENTERTAINMENT

DIGITAL DOMAIN

BILL PAXTON

Courtesy of WGBH-TV/BOSTON
```

Comment: I hope this is on topic here, but if not, someone please suggest where on the network it may be on topic.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information about where to find the footage you are talking about (Like time into a chapter of the movie or whatever).

Comment: @OrganicMarble Absolutely; here you go. I have been looking for the documentary where I saw the longer clips for what seems like years, and this is the first actual lead I have noticed that might actually bring me closer to finding that one.

Comment: I think it would be fair use for you to upload maybe 20 seconds long clip to ask the question. Especially since the material seems to be NASA footage, and thus public domain.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Unfortunately there is no such concept as fair use under Swedish copyright law, so technically uploading even a single frame that is covered by copyright would be a violation. I might look around to see if anyone else has uploaded it, though, and provide a link...

Comment: But if it is NASA footage, then it is public domain, and you can use it as you like.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Indeed, but I don't know where the footage is originally from. It *stands to reason* that it's at least partially NASA footage, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: Another thought: There should be a reference to the source of borrowed material somewhere on the dvd...

Comment: I can't find a definitive source for the claim, but apparently none of the footage in the film is from NASA or other period sources. All of it was filmed for the movie, and processed to _look_ like it was old (i.e. added grain, lowered resolution). So if this material was shot for the movie and either cut or moved to bonus features it would still have been filmed in the 1990s _for the movie_.